# Change zoom yandex map

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Появилась проблема, как мне поймать событие изменения zoom на карте yandex API. Мне необходимо показывать различную информацию по мере приближения, или удаления от объекта.

Я собираю данные в json, помещаю в objectManager, и после к лика на объект появляется информация, также мне необходимо при приближении менять информацию. Сперва о городе, потом о районе, и уже при клике на марку, информация о марке. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, поймать событие, то есть правильно его записать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать к примеру так:

```
map.events.add('boundschange', function(e){
        if (e.get('newZoom') !== e.get('oldZoom')) {
            console.log('zoomchange')
        }
    })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gaqtrfwb/

Comment: Спасибо большое. А я могу как-нибудь поставить число, на которое должна зуммироваться карта. Как в начале при инициализации мы пишем Zomm: 9. Только, чтобы при zomm она менялась на 2, например.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы при любом зуме на карте, будь то зум колесом мыши, зум даблкликом, зум тапом, клик по контролу зума, у вас зум происходил на два уровня вместо одного? Зачем вам это поведение? Если вы хотите зумиться на два уровня зума в некоторых случаях, например по клике на метке, то можно написать так map.setZoom(map.getZoom + 2);